# Styling of remembered user name drop down box

Tags: html, css

Most (maybe all) browsers show a drop down list of previously used user names when logging into a website.

Is it possible to style this drop down, or is it browser specific?

Comment: You mean the Autocomplete option on a Text Input? This is not username specific.

Comment: you should really turn off autocomplete on username fields

Comment: Yes, the autocomplete, and your right Pete, I should turn it off on username fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't style them as they are not really a part of the webpage itself.

If you're making your own website though, you could make your own drop-down list, which gets a list of recently used usernames, and style that how you want it. But you'll need to use, for example, javscript or php to do that, and it's just completely unnecessary.

And besides, a user should really only have one account on a website.